# Use Visual Studio DLL to format a .cs file

Tags: c#, .net, format

I'd like to build an executable which takes in input some piece of c# code and reformat as Visual Studio would do.

For reformat I mean the following definition:
"Reformatting affects braces layout, blank lines, line wrapping and line breaks, spaces in various contexts, indentation, aligning multiple constructs, and a lot more options that you can fine-tune"

Is it possible to use any Visual Studio public API or directly the .NET Framework to reformat a piece of code? Or do you know any other framework that offers this functionality?

Comment: Define 'format a piece of code'.

Comment: Do you mean format a piece of code within Visual Studio that you're currently working on? Or, as part of your program, you want to allow a user to paste code and your program formats it?

Comment: Visual Studio supports Automation.  Which lets you load a file into the editor and use the Edit + Advanced + Format Document command.  So yes.  If that's not what you are looking for then do note that you can type more than a single sentence in a question.

Comment: keyboardP: the second one. I want to build a c# executables that allows user to paste some lines of code and it reformats the code in the same manner as Visual Studio would reformat.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Visual Studio provides public API for such tasks but you can try open source code formatted like [NArrange](http://www.narrange.net/)